# sharepoint 2010 get value of choice field through api call

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, rest, ajax

I have a sharepoint list `ImageList`, i have a column which stores its type

The column name is `ImageType`

the choices are *"profile pic","thumbnail"* etc

i want to fetch these choice values for this field

i tried accessing it using

```
http://myintranet:2010/sites/ImagesGallery/_vti_bin/listdata.svc/ImageList?$Select=ImageType&$expand=ImageType
```

but it is not containing the choice values in it!

How can i get them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the choice values from `listdata.svc` you need to make a request against the correct `EntitySet`...

You can think of an `EntitySet` as any list that `listdata.svc` has access to -- this includes choice field choices.

Choice field EntitySets will typically have an endpoint name that looks like:

```
<ListName><ChoiceFieldName>
```

So if I have a list called `MyList` which has a choice field called `MyChoiceField`, then a call to the entity set name that can be accessed by `listdata.svc` would be have an endpoint of:

```
_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyListMyChoiceField
```

To find the precise name of the `EntitySet` you should be looking for, make a call to the top level endpoint `listdata.svc` in the site you're interested in.

Use something like:

```
$.getJSON('../_vti_bin/listdata.svc').then(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

In your browser dev tools console, expand the result object. The results should be alphabetical by default, find your list name then below it you should see some more choices for choice fields within that specific list.

When you locate the correct endpoint name, just make a call to that `EntitySet` name like:

```
$.getJSON('../_vti_bin/listdata.svc/MyListMyChoiceField')
    .then(function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

The results to the call against the choice field endpoint will give you a `results` object which is an Array of objects representing the available choices for that field. You can access the values of the choices by using `data.d.results[i].Value` in the callback.

Comment: if you can let me know where i can learn more about this it will be helpful for me